# Unable to append to an Oracle table from R Server using dbAppendTable()

Tags: java, r, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I have created a table in the oracle database from a dataframe using the following code:

```
drv_oracle <- JDBC(oracle_driver, oracle_jdbc_jar)  #creating DBI driver
conn_oracle <- dbConnect(drv_oracle, oracle_url,"username","password")  #creating DBIConnection Object

dbWriteTable(conn_oracle,"DECILE_ANALYSIS_BASE_TABLE",DECILE_ANALYSIS_FINAL) #DECILE_ANALYSIS_FINAL is dataframe
```

Using the above code, the table is created in the database.

But now I have refreshed the DECILE_ANALYSIS_FINAL dataframe with new data. I want to append this data into my created table.

This I try to do using following code:

```
conn_oracle <- dbConnect(drv_oracle, oracle_url,"username","password") 
dbAppendTable(conn_oracle,"DECILE_ANALYSIS_BASE_TABLE",DECILE_ANALYSIS_FINAL)
```

But now I am getting following error:

```
Error in dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
  Statement: INSERT INTO "DECILE_ANALYSIS_BASE_TABLE"
  ("FISCAL_YEAR", "MONTH", "GEO_LEVEL", "GEO_CODE", "PRODUCT_LEVEL", "PRODUCT_CODE", "CHANNEL_TYPE", "DECILE", "UOB", "TULC", "TTLC", "TOTAL_SALES", "PDO", "UNIQUE_ID", "AVG_PDO_DROP")
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Please help me understand how I can resolve this issue.

I tried the code mentioned above